# Facebook profile image and download it to my web directory

Tags: php, javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

Take a Facebook profile image and download it to my directory "www.site.com/images"..

```
<?php $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=350&height=500&redirect=false"; ?>
```

The variable "$id" is taken from a textfield, I've tried getting around the "redirect" that facebook places on their images, so to get the "real url" I've decided to extract it from a JSON. In browser I receive this:

```
  "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofil[...]",
  "width": 299,
  "height": 426,
  "is_silhouette": false
```

All I need is the "real url" to be extracted and saved unto my website's directory.

$.getJSON, seems to be the easiest way to separate the information.

Summary

- Extracting/Separator script for JSON in PHP or JAVASCRIPT
- Or Save "Image" to "Directory".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solutions:

### PHP with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=350&height=500&redirect=false");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // Mean 5 seconds
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  $data = json_decode($content, true);
  curl_close($ch);
  var_dump($data["data"]["url"]);
```

### PHP with file_get_contents()

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=350&height=500&redirect=false");
  $data = json_decode($content, true);
  var_dump($data["data"]["url"]);
```

### javascript with jQuery

```
var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture?width=350&height=500&redirect=false";
$.get(url,function(resp) {
  alert(resp.data.url);
});
```

### EDIT

Have you tried to remove "&redirect=false"

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=350&height=500"
redirect to
"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofil[...]"
```

So you can do:

```
<?php
  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?width=350&height=500";
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $fp = fopen("img$id.jpg","wb");
  if (!$fp) exit;
  fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp);
```

Learn more about [picture graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

Comment: SWEET, thanks man, cURL + file_get_contents() were disabled on my hosting but the jQuery works great!

Answer (score 0):

I used this code when storing images from fb.

```
$dir = "your_directory";
$img = md5(time()).'.jpg';
$url = "some_value";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$img, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```